# Como criar um gráfico com dois eixos y com diferentes escalas no R?

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, plot

Estou tentando plotar um gráfico com 3 conjuntos de dados. "Precipitação" e "Evapotranspiração" tem valores altos (de 5 a 580) então usaria a mesma escala em Y (do lado esquero) para ambos os dados plotados sobrepostos em gráfico de linha. Os dados de "Dias com chuva" (que variam de 3 a 28), quero plotar no mesmo gráfico porém com uma escala em Y própria (do lado direito).

Tentei:

```
plot(etp,type="l",ylim=c(5,580),col="turquoise",ylab="pluviosidade",xlab="mês)
lines(prec,col="turquoise3")
abline(v=seq(1,121,12),lty=2, col="gray")
lines(dcch,type="l",lwd="2",mar=c(5,4,2,5),ylim=c(3,28),col="darkorchid3",ylab="dias com chuva",xlab="mês")
axis(side=4,ylim=c(3,28),line=3,ylab="dias com chuva")
```

E tentei também:

```
plot(etp,type="l",ylim=c(5,580),col="turquoise",ylab="pluviosidade",xlab="mês")
lines(prec,col="turquoise3")
lines(dcch,type="l",lwd="2",col="darkorchid3")
abline(v=seq(1,121,12),lty=2, col="gray")
par(new=TRUE)
axis(side=2,ylim=c(5,580))
axis(side=4,ylim=c(0,30))
```

Onde está o erro?

Comment: disponibilize seu conjunto de dados, ou uma parte do mesmo, com o comando `dput` para o seu problema ser reproduzível

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro esta, provalvemente, em tenta plotar "Dias de chuva" antes de `par(new = TRUE)`.
Além disso, depois de `par(new = TRUE)` você tem que criar um novo `plot()` para então plotar linhas com o `lines()`.

Tentei modificar seu código sem seus dados, mas como Rafael Cunha destacou, é importante que nas próximas perguntas você sempre disponibilize uma parte dos dados para tornar o exemplo reproduzível.

```
par(mar = c(4, 4, 1, 4)) # aumentar a margem do gráfico no lado direto
plot(etp, type = "l", ylim = c(5, 580), col = "turquoise", ylab = "pluviosidade", xlab = "mês")
lines(prec, col = "turquoise3")
abline(v = seq(1, 121, 12), lty = 2, col = "gray")
par(new = TRUE) # adicionar nova janela gráfica sobre a janela interior
plot(etp, pch = "", ylim = c(0, 30), yaxt = "n", ylab = "", xlab = "") # plotar gráfico sem informações
lines(dcch, type = "l", lwd = "2", col = "darkorchid3")
axis(side = 4, ylim = c(0, 30)) 
mtext("Dias com chuva", side = 4, line = 3)
```